# Dealing with strings in UTF-8 in java and python

Tags: java, python, encoding, utf-8

I am piping a UTF-8 string from python to java using the subprocess call

For python

```
import subprocess

thai = u"คำบางคำไทย"
thai = thai.encode('utf-8')
p = subprocess.Popen(["java", "-jar", "hi.jar"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(thai)


print ":".join(x.encode('hex') for x in thai)
```

For Java

I am assuming i piped in the String using

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)
String thai = in.nextline()
String byte_rep = String.format("%40x", new BigInteger(1, thai.getBytes("utf-8")));
System.out.println(byte_rep)
```

However, the 2 different hex representations seems to be different. Is there any error with my piping?

Comment: your python snippet has "p.communicate(l)".  is that a typo?

Comment: the problem is most likely that you are converting the bytes to a String in java using the default character encoding.  try `new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping those bytes to a bufferreader object in java I believe @jtahlborn might be right?